Missing libcrypt.so in Fedora
While trying to use the pre-built version of Paraview (v5.12) in Fedora 40, I got this error message:
/opt/ParaView-5.12.0-MPI-Linux-Python3.10-x86_64/bin/paraview-real: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


In fedora 40, it was necessary the installation of the following package, to place the library libcrypt.so into the system :
sudo dnf install libxcrypt-compat 

